# Grant privileges to all users, current and future

Tags: postgresql, database-design, privileges

I have a multi-schema, multi-user Postgres DB.  There is one table that I would like ALL users, both current and future, to be able to SELECT from.

I can GRANT SELECT to all current users... but how can I create a table that allows any future user to select?  Is there a way to set table *permissions*, rather than granting user *privileges*?

A filesystem analogy would be using `chmod` to make a file to be readable by the public.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
grant select on the_table to public;
```

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html):

> *The key word PUBLIC indicates that the privileges are to be granted to all roles, including those that might be created later. PUBLIC can be thought of as an implicitly defined group that always includes all roles*

Comment: nice! just figured this out myself! For a more general solution, I can GRANT SELECT to a particular ROLE and then make sure that new users are created in that ROLE.