# How to setup vault and Postgres in Google cloud to have the correct permissions?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, google-cloud-sql, hashicorp-vault

## The Problem

I am trying to setup [Hashicorp vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) and Postgres in Google Cloud.

I am using liquibase to manage the schema and when that does a migration, it retrieves a username/password from vault and then runs under that user to perform the migration.

However, the default postgres user, or any other user that tries to use that table can't and receives the `ERROR:  permission denied for relation`.

If I understand correctly, the users are being created while logged into as the role of `postgres`. This all works locally but the google cloud stuff seems to be setup in a vastly different way.

Here are some outputs to see what the database is setup as:

```
\du
                                                List of roles
            Role name             |                         Attributes                         |      Member of
----------------------------------+------------------------------------ 
------------------------+---------------------
 cloudsqladmin                    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, 
Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 cloudsqlagent                    | Create role, Create DB                                     
| {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 cloudsqlreplica                  | Replication                                                
| {}
 cloudsqlsuperuser                | Create role, Create DB                                     
| {}
 postgres                         | Create role, Create DB                                     
| {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 test                             | Create role, Create DB                                     
| {cloudsqlsuperuser}
 v-token-power-watc-p079t4r13s85w | Password valid until              
| {cloudsqlsuperuser}


\dt
                            List of relations
 Schema |         Name          | Type  |              Owner
--------+-----------------------+-------+------------------------------ 
 public | databasechangelog     | table | v-token-power-watc-p079t4r13s85w
 public | databasechangeloglock | table | v-token-power-watc-p079t4r13s85w
 public | test                  | table | v-token-power-watc-p079t4r13s85w
```

The vault creation SQL looks something like this:

```
CREATE ROLE "{{name}}" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "{{name}}"; 
GRANT cloudsqlsuperuser to "{{name}}";"
```

I've tried playing with the roles in a number of ways but it seems all of the new roles that I create are always put into their own sandbox and can't play with any other roles. I'm at a lost at this point of exactly what to do next, it seems that no matter the `grant` options I can pass, it doens't help.

## Current Questions

Is it that the owner needs to be the cloudsqlsuperuser group instead of the temp ownwer?

Is there a way to make that the default instead of having to make sure all my tables are created with the right owner?

## Replicate with a local docker instance

**Docker Command to start Postgres Database**

```
docker run --rm --name database -v $(pwd)/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql -e POSTGRES_USER=temp -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb postgres:9.6
```

**Contents of setup.sql**

```
ALTER ROLE postgres RENAME TO cloudsqladmin;
CREATE ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE;
ALTER DATABASE mydb OWNER TO cloudsqlsuperuser;
CREATE ROLE "postgres" WITH LOGIN CREATEDB CREATEROLE IN ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser;
```

**Creating user under postgres simulating vault user creation**

```
docker exec -ti database psql -U postgres -d mydb -c "CREATE ROLE testuser WITH LOGIN IN ROLE cloudsqlsuperuser"
```

**Create test table from testuser**

```
docker exec -ti database psql -U testuser -d mydb -c "CREATE TABLE test (col1 text)"
```

**Try and select table demonstrating error**

```
docker exec -ti database psql -U postgres -d mydb -c "SELECT * FROM test"
```

Comment: Yes I know that if I add `superuser` to the postgres role this just works, however google-cloud-sql doesn't allow superuser access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Summary**

You have to run an `REASSIGN OWNED BY "$VAULT_USERNAME" TO "cloudsqlsuperuser"` after the table/sequence/function creation process to reassign back to a the common role.

**Longer Answer**

[Postgres 9.6 `CREATE TABLE` will by default create the table under the user's role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html). Because the vault user is designed to be a temporary credential, we need to also make sure that the objects created under the temporary roles are reassigned back to a common role of some kind. In the specific case I outlined in Google Cloud, we are going to reassign back to `cloudsqlsuperuser`.

The one command I found to work is the `REASSIGN OWNED BY current_user to "cloudsqlsuperuser"` command that will then take all of the objects owned by that temporary user and assign back to that common role.

**Bonus: liquibase config**

I am using liquibase to do my migrations and this is in my change log to fix the permissions everytime we run a migration:

```
<databaseChangeLog>
    <changeSet author="elindblom" id="fix-permissions" context="" logicalFilePath="fix-permissions" runAlways="true" runOrder="last">
        <sqlFile path="baselines/sql/fix-permissions.sql" splitStatements="false" relativeToChangelogFile="true" stripComments="false"/>
    </changeSet>
   ... rest of your change logs after ...
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The SQL looks like this:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY current_user TO "cloudsqlsuperuser";
```

The `changeSet` runs after everything comes to completion and runs every-time. The very important bits are the `runAlways` and `runOrder` elements.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here has to do with the new table being created under that temporary user - your other users won't have the privileges to access it. There are a couple of ways you could try solving this.

The first is to grant privileges for each table after it's created. You'll have to adjust this accordingly to the roles you want to give access to, but if you just want **all** users (current and future) to have full access), you can use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <table> TO public;` as stated [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246432/1091015)

**A better solution might be** to use only a single user to create all tables. You can still have Vault generate a new password for it on demand and revoke access to it automatically, even if the username is the same. To do this, you'll have to **manually** create the user and give it the privileges you want first - assuming you name it `migrator`:

```
CREATE ROLE migrator;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "migrator";
```

Then change your Vault configuration to add the login privilege when you request for credentials, and remove it when you revoke them:

```
vault write <role path here, e.g. database/roles/migrator> \
    db_name=<db name here> \
    creation_statements="ALTER ROLE migrator LOGIN PASSWORD '{{password}}' VALID UNTIL '{{expiration}}';" \
    revocation_statements="ALTER ROLE migrator NOLOGIN;"
```

The advantage of doing this is that you can then use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` ([docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)) to save you from having to grant privileges for each and every new table that gets created. For example, if you know that all users should have access to everything:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE migrator GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO PUBLIC
```

I'm not sure how postgres reacts if you delete a user that is the owner of a table, but if there's an issue with that then this solution would fix that too.

Comment: That was damn near close to what I got working in the end. I've posted my answer to what I've worked out in the end. Thank you for the suggestions!